# Cucumber report starting with "When" instead of "Given"

Tags: junit, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

When running a test using this JUnit runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions (
        features = "C:\\myfeature.feature",
        glue = {"stepmethods"},
        plugin = {pretty},
        junit = "--step-notifications",
        dryRun = false
)

public class RunTest {

}
```

and with a standard feature file

```
**Given** I'm on the homepage
**When** I enter the correct credentials
**And** I click submit
**Then** I will get a userlist
```

when I run this console log shows that the test starts with the **When** keyword. (I know this because I occasionally print to console some checkpoints.)

If I comment out the **When**, **And** and **Then** steps, I get the correct output.

What could be the issue?

**UPDATE:**

Tests run in the right order, but they are not logged to console in the same order.
It seems this has to do with `plugin = {pretty}` option. When it is excluded, logging seems fine.

I would still like to keep this option. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is your question about the running of the steps or the reporting of the steps?

Comment: It is about the reporting. Steps run in right order.

Comment: Yes, I figured from the update. Maybe you could rephrase your question? Also, afaik this is expected behaviour; steps are not guaranteed to be reported in order.

Comment: I edited the title. This could be the expected behaviour, but why wouldn't the steps be reported in the right order.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it, that might be only when running in parallel. I'm not sure tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting pretty between double-quotes and adding a report type.

```
@CucumberOptions (
    features = "C:\\myfeature.feature",
    glue = {"stepmethods"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:some/dir"},
    junit = "--step-notifications",
    dryRun = false
)
```

Comment: Please post the "Given I'm on the homepage" step definition.  While it shouldn't matter since cucumber escapes the characters, also try removing the single-quote.

Comment: If you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then we could reproduce the behavior on our machines. This would be necessary in any case to open a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give below way also working

```
@CucumberOptions 
(
features = "C:\\myfeature.feature",

glue = {"stepmethods"},

plugin = {"pretty", "html:some/dir"},

stepNotifications=true,

dryRun = false

)
```